# Get list of changed files from remote server git

Tags: git, svn, github

Is there a hook that gives the file name as soon as someone commits their change and merges with master from remote server? . I basically want to get a trigger that someone has updated a file on remote repo. Details like what file has been changed.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Could you please add some more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Chris what I want is to get a notification sort of thing when someone updates on remote repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GitHub's [email service](https://help.github.com/articles/receiving-email-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/):

> Emails sent by the email service are different from [regular notifications](https://help.github.com/articles/about-notifications); they don't show up on the web, and they provide different contextual information.
>
> Email services send the following information:
>
> - The name of the repository where the commit was made.
> - The branch a commit was made in.
> - The SHA1 of the commit, including a link to the diff in GitHub.
> - The author of the commit.
> - The date when the commit was made.
> - The files that were changed as part of the commit.
> - The commit message.

Enable the **Email** service via the **Webhooks & Services** section in your repository's settings panel. More detailed instructions are available at the link shown above.

This GitHub service is likely triggered by Git's native [`post-update`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-update) or [`post-receive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook, but since GitHub's source code is not available and this doesn't seem to be documented it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: This is specific to GitHub right. l would like to know the actual hook that triggers this email

Comment: @iLoveCamelCase, your question is tagged with [tag:github] so I provided an answer for GitHub. I've updated it with some suppositions about how GitHub's Email service might work with respect to Git's native hooks.